# greatest-n-per-group with lambda expressions in EF core 2.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write a lambda query to retrieve all products that are available for rent or soon available (where End date is in 10 days). The query will return all products that are never rented before or the products are rented but will be available soon.

```
   public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rent> Rents { get; set; }
}

public class Rent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Normally the SQL query for this is as below:

```
SELECT p.*, r1.*
FROM Products p
LEft JOIN Rents r1 ON (p.id = r1.ProductId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rents r2 ON (p.id = r2.ProductId AND 
    (r1.CreationTime < r2.CreationTime OR r1.CreationTime = r2.CreationTime AND r1.id < r2.id))
WHERE r2.id IS NULL AND (r1.EndDate is NULL OR r1.EndDate<='2018-06-24');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: People will be more willing to help you if you show them that at least you tried something

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use something like this:

```
from p in db.Products
let r = p.Rents.OrderByDescending(r => r.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault()
where r == null || r.EndDate <= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(10)
select new { p, r }
```

Unfortunately even in the latest at this time EF Core 2.1 this leads to N + 1 queries.

So instead you could use the LINQ equivalent of your SQL query. Just instead of the second anti-join you should use the LINQ equivalent of the SQL `NOT EXISTS` construct (i.e. `!Any`):

```
from p in db.Products
from r in p.Rents.DefaultIfEmpty()
where r == null || (r.EndDate <= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(10) &&
    !p.Rents.Any(r2 => r.CreationTime < r2.CreationTime || (r.CreationTime == r2.CreationTime && r.Id < r2.Id)))
select new { p, r }
```

which nicely translates to a single SQL query.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems to be working with one exception that when I introduce extra filters followed by r.EndDate<= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(10 || r.UrgentReturnDate!=null && !p.Rents.Any(...)  this breaks the second option. The first option still works but as you said that the generated query is N +1. Any reason that extra filters would break the second query? Knowing that UrgentReturnDate can be null.

Comment: It depends how you apply these additional filters. `!p.Rents.Any(…)` enforces the "last" condition, so it should be *and*-ed will all other conditions, e.g. `(r.EndDate<= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(10 || r.UrgentReturnDate!=null) && !p.Rents.Any(...)` - in your example the criteria is evaluates like `r.EndDate<= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(10 || (r.UrgentReturnDate!=null && !p.Rents.Any(...))` since `&&` has higher priority than `||`.

Comment: I have done that too but it is weird that I keep getting randomly 'Evaluating the function 'function' timed out and needed to be aborted in an unsafe way' exception. I will investigate this further and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly: first include the navigation property:

```
var result = ctx.Products.Include(n => n.Rents)
```

> The query will return all products that are never rented before or

then check for where `Rents` is null

```
result.Where(product => product.Rents == null ...
```

> or the products are rented but will be available soon

```
result.Where(product => product.Rents == null || product.Rents.Max(rent => rent.EndDate) <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(10))
```